# finding the ratio when two other ratios are given

Tags: ratio

The ratio of incomes of a  and b is 3:4 and ratio of their expenditure is 4:5 . what can be their possible ratio of savings 9:10 or 3:4 or 4:5 or 13:20.
            I don't find anything suitable in the options I think the answer is 2:3 but it has to be from the choices.

Comment: You are looking for the ratio: $\dfrac{a-c}{b-d}$. With $a = 0.75b, c = 0.8d$, can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

We can scale everything in terms of A's income, so call that $1$.  B's income is then $\frac 43$.  Let A's expenses be $x$, which makes B's expenses $\frac 54x$.  A's savings are $1-x$, while B's are $\frac 43-\frac 54x$, giving a ratio of $\frac {1-x}{\frac 43-\frac 54x}=\frac {12-12x}{16-15x}$.  We are now asked which of the given ratios can match this fraction.  If $x=0$, so there are no expenses, the ratio is $3:4$.  I think you are supposed to think this is not possible.  As $x$ increases toward $1$, the ratio decreases toward zero.  The only choice that is less than $3:4$ is $13:20$ so that must be the intended answer.

However, if I solve $\frac {12-12x}{16-15x}=\frac 9{10}$  I get a [perfectly good answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2812-12x%29%2F%2816-15x%29%3D9%2F10) of $x=\frac 85$.  In that cases both peoples expenses exceed their income.  A is saving $-\frac 35$ and B is saving $-\frac 23$, which gives the proper ratio.  We cannot get a ratio of $\frac 45$, but can get as close as we want if $x$ gets very large.